# how to specify all values for a parameter in robots.txt and sitemap.xml?

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have a php file that extracts a post id from a url's parameter to show a specific post content. for example it uses the `postid` parameter from the following url to show the post content with id of 21:
`example.com/mydir/posts.php?postid=21`
the `postid` is dynamic and every time that a user post a content a new post id will be added to the database.
**how can I specify this php file in my `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`?**
Currently, I use the following:
robots.txt:

`Disallow: /mydir/
Allow: /mydir/posts.php?username=*`

sitmap.xml:
`<loc>example.com/mydir/posts.php?postid=*</loc>`

Comment: Why are you disallowing `/mydir/`?    Many robots don't understand `Allow:` rules.  It would be more widely understood to just disallow the portions of `/mydir/` that you don't want crawlers to hit.

Comment: XML sitemaps don't support wildcards.   Your XML sitemap should list many `posts.php?postid=` URLs.  It should have a list of all the valid post ids.